# How to stop ps( aka parameter server) when using tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow1.4 and very interested in tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate because of the distribution.

But, I can't find a way to stop ps and have to kill it manually.

Is there any way to stop ps when finishing training using TensorFlow?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue in TF 1.7

Comment: the same with 1.9